# Kafka Streams aggregate stateful IoT data

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have incoming data for cars and wanna create a new event for journeys. I have the following json message from the vehicle-event topic:

```
{ asset_id: ‘123’, location: [11.00, 12.00], journey_start: true }
{ asset_id: ‘123’, location: [12.00, 12.00] }
{ asset_id: ‘123’, location: [13.00, 12.00], journey_end: true }
```

From the journey event start until the journey event end it should collect the locations and if the journey ended it should send it to the journey-event topic. With the prev example the message should be

```
{ asset_id: ‘123’, locations: [[11.00, 12.00], [12.00, 12.00], [13.00, 12.00]] }
```

Once there is a new journey start event it should discard the previous journey event from the local store.

This is what I have so far. I don't know how to do the aggregation, add a conditional to push to the journey-event topic, and delete the old location data:

```
public class Stream {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Properties config = new Properties();
        config.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "stream");
        config.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
        config.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());
        config.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());
        config.put(StreamsConfig.PROCESSING_GUARANTEE_CONFIG, StreamsConfig.EXACTLY_ONCE);

        final Serializer<JsonNode> jsonSerializer = new JsonSerializer();
        final Deserializer<JsonNode> jsonDeserializer = new JsonDeserializer();
        final Serde<JsonNode> jsonSerde = Serdes.serdeFrom(jsonSerializer, jsonDeserializer);

        StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
        KStream<String, JsonNode> vehicleEvent = builder.stream(
            "vehicle-event",
            Consumed.with(
                Serdes.String(),
                jsonSerde
            )
        );

        KStream<String, JsonNode> journeyEvent = vehicleEvent
            .groupBy((key, value) -> {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(value);
                return jsonObj.getString("asset_id");
            })
            .aggregate()


    Topology topology = builder.build();
    KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(topology, config);
    streams.start();
}
```

}

Comment: Once you use `aggregate`, the `KGroupedStream` you get by grouping-by becomes a `KTable`. In that case you won't need any extra processing to manage the conditional push you mentioned, since the `KTable` acts in this case as a changelog, and the Materialized view in the state store would only keep the latest (rolling) aggregate for each key (according to the documentation here for the `aggregate` method with `Materialized` as third argument: https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/javadocs/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/KGroupedStream.html).

Comment: The DSL does not support what you want to do. You will need to use the processor API that allows for more flexibility with regard to state handling.